# How to see raw content of a TAR file with GVIM or VI?

Tags: vim

I'm developing a program which creates TAR files via MTP on the fly. For this reason I want to see the "raw content" of the TAR file - and not the extracted content.

It does not need to be the hex view, just the content would be enough. I thought "gvim -b" (binary) would do the trick... but I still get the file listing. My current workaround is to rename the file to "*.dat" to see the raw content... but this is ugly. Further more, on Windows I get only the error message "tar not available on your system" and nothing is displayed - instead of showing the raw content...

Answer (score 6):

That's because the default *TAR plugin* (cp. `:help pi_tar`) is still active and intercepts file edits of `*.tar` files. To temporarily turn it off, launch Vim with

```
$ vim --cmd "let g:loaded_tarPlugin = 1" -b myFile.tar
```

Alternatively, and to turn off the plugin after Vim has started, you can also use the following command:

```
:au! tar
```

Comment: Or, to permanently disable this behaviour, you can put `let g:loaded_tarPlugin = 1` in your `.vimrc`.

Comment: Another alternative:  Start vim without editing any files, `$ vim`.  Then `:let loaded_tarPlugin = 1` (the `:g` is optional) and `:e myFile.tar`.